# Example for Supervised Machine Learning Classification for more than 2 dependent variables

Tags: machine-learning

Where can I find a supervised classification machine learning example for categorical dependent variables?

For example :

Lizard as insect, Flies as insect, Mosquitoes as insect, Monkey as mammal, Bear as mammal, Sharks as fish, Guppies as fish, Finland as country, USA as country, Japan as Country, 
Apple Inc as Company, Berkshire Hathaway Inc as Company, Merck & Co., Inc as Company........

I have taken Udemy Machine Learning A-Z and all the scenarios taught were for only 2 dependent variables (Yes or No, 1 or 0). Anyone knows where can I find Python codes or learning example for classifying texts into country, company, insects, etc, ie. more than 2 dependent variables?

Thanks

@David Dale, I tried :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('Test31Oct17.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsOneClassifier
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
OneVsOneClassifier(LinearSVC(random_state=0)).fit(X, y).predict(X)`
```

It didn't work. It says *ValueError: could not convert string to float: '14fl., no.66, san-chung rd., nangang dist'*

For y, i alreadt changed all the classifications into 1,2,3,4... etc instead of fish, country, mammals etc

Answer (score 0):

The [UCI Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/) should give you plenty of examples with what you are asking - you can search there for Classification problems with more than 2 classes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you ask not about *multiple dependent variables*, but about *one MULTICLASS dependent variable*.

Many ML algorithms (from logistic regression to decision trees and their ensembles) support multiclass classification naturally. Other algorithms (such as SVM) in their basic form cannot handle multiclass problems. But several such binary models can be aggregated in *one-versus-one* or *one-versus-rest* fashion.

As an example, scikit-learn [supports](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html) multiclass classification, and even more difficult cases - multilabel and multitask classification (yep, they are all different problems).

Comment: import numpy as np
%matplotlib.inline
import pandas as pd


dataset = pd.read_csv('Test31Oct17.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, 0].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 1].values

from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsOneClassifier
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
OneVsOneClassifier(LinearSVC(random_state=0)).fit(X, y).predict(X)/n

Comment: Can you provide an example with data, so that I could debug it?

Comment: Hi David, Please see the code on my original post right on top. This is the csv file.: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xx315vo98c6tod/Test31Oct17%20Dropbox.csv?dl=0

Comment: It says "ValueError: could not convert string to float"

Comment: I also tried using NLTK's Named Entity Recognition. It says : "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object". The code is here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/e23amre2esrjhp3/BusinessCards.py?dl=0

Comment: Well, the problem is that your X is a 1d array of text strings. However, scikit-learn classifiers accept only 2d matrices of numbers. I think you should start with scikit-learn tutorial: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html

Comment: And in any case, your problem is really DIFFICULT.  You want your model to memorize that 'Executive' is a business role and 'Jakarta' is a toponym with ONLY ONE example and NO FEATURES. Any model you use on such data will likely OVERFIT. Sorry for my Caps, but please go study some math before asking questions about implementation.

Comment: Hi David, the excel csv file is just an example database that i produced quickly to show you the scenario. To train the model, I will need to load it with many more thousands of examples. Yeah, i also think it is a difficult task being assigned to me. Since this does not work, I will try NLP Named Entity Recognition method instead. Thanks.